# Copy paste 1 column in batches

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy paste 1 large column (200.000 rows) in batches of about 500 with a delay of 1 second in between and paste them to sheet Y with a macro. Sounds easy but I've been looking through some topics and can't get it to work.

Using Excel 2013.

**EDIT**

```
Sub batchpaste()

Dim a As Worksheet
Dim b As Worksheet


Set a = Sheets("Sheet1") 'replace with your source sheet
Set b = Sheets("Sheet2") 'replace with your destination sheet

neverRan = False
counter = 10
startRow = 1
For c = 1 To a.Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last column
beginning:
    lastrow = a.Cells(65536, c).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
    If lastrow <= counter Then
        b.Range(b.Cells(startRow, c), b.Cells(lastrow, c)).Value = a.Range(a.Cells(startRow, c), a.Cells(lastrow, c)).Value
        counter = 10
        startRow = 1
        neverRan = False
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:05 AM#) 'enter seconds of delay here (set at 1 seconds right now)
    ElseIf neverRan = False Then
        b.Range(b.Cells(startRow, c), b.Cells(counter, c)).Value = a.Range(a.Cells(startRow, c), a.Cells(counter, c)).Value
        startRow = startRow + 10
        counter = counter + 10
        neverRan = True
        GoTo beginning
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:05 AM#) 'enter seconds of delay here (set at 1 seconds right now)
    Else
        b.Range(b.Cells(startRow, c), b.Cells(counter, c)).Value = a.Range(a.Cells(startRow, c), a.Cells(counter, c)).Value
        startRow = startRow + 10
        counter = counter + 10
        GoTo beginning
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:05 AM#) 'enter seconds of delay here (set at 1 seconds right now)
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub asdf()

    Dim a As Worksheet
    Dim b As Worksheet

    Set a = Sheets("Sheet2") 'replace with your source sheet
    Set b = Sheets("Sheet3") 'replace with your destination sheet

    For c = 1 To a.Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last column
        lastrow = a.Cells(65536, c).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
        b.Range(b.Cells(1, c), b.Cells(lastrow, c)).Value = a.Range(a.Cells(1, c), a.Cells(lastrow, c)).Value
    Next c

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

```
Sub asdf()

    Dim a As Worksheet
    Dim b As Worksheet

    Set a = Sheets("Sheet1") 'replace with your source sheet
    Set b = Sheets("Sheet2") 'replace with your destination sheet

    neverRan = False
    counter = 1000
    startRow = 1
    For c = 1 To a.Range("iv1").End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last column
beginning:
        lastrow = a.Cells(65536, c).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
        If lastrow <= counter Then
            b.Range(b.Cells(startRow, c), b.Cells(lastrow, c)).Value = a.Range(a.Cells(startRow, c), a.Cells(lastrow, c)).Value
            counter = 1000
            startRow = 1
            neverRan = False
            Application.wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#) 'enter seconds of delay here (set at 1 seconds right now)
        ElseIf neverRan = False Then
            b.Range(b.Cells(startRow, c), b.Cells(counter, c)).Value = a.Range(a.Cells(startRow, c), a.Cells(counter, c)).Value
            startRow = startRow + 1000
            counter = counter + 1000
            neverRan = True
            GoTo beginning
            Application.wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#) 'enter seconds of delay here (set at 1 seconds right now)
        Else
            b.Range(b.Cells(startRow, c), b.Cells(counter, c)).Value = a.Range(a.Cells(startRow, c), a.Cells(counter, c)).Value
            startRow = startRow + 1000
            counter = counter + 1000
            GoTo beginning
            Application.wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#) 'enter seconds of delay here (set at 1 seconds right now)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this VBA. I tested it with just 12 rows in column A, and it's already taking longer than 5 minutes. Any idea why it's taking so long?

Also, where can I set the delay and the batch size (how many rows at a time)?

Comment: this is the only code in your vba?  on my machine i ran 3 million records in about 2 seconds

Comment: Jellz, you are right. It has to do with my sheet. Say it pastes the data in A, then there's a formula in B that retrieves data (using a database) using the information in A. Because it instantly starts calculating it causes the VBA to take longer.

This however is a minor issue. The issue is that the database only allows X requests per minute. So when I fire a million rows into A the formula in B will crash. That is why I would like to do it in batches of 1000 with a few seconds of delay in between.

Comment: Thanks, going to check it out!

Comment: Hi Jellz,

I tested it with 200 rows, 10 rows at a time with a 5 second delay (see the code in my original post). I have screenupdating on, I can see it pasting the first 10, then waiting 5 seconds, and the instantly pasting the remaining 190. Any idea why it doesn't stick to steps of 10?

Comment: @Dechesne are you able to step through the code you're running?  not sure your level of vba, but using F8 will walk through the lines step by step to show you exactly what the macro is doing.  happy to help if you're still having trouble after stepping through the code.  i ran my test again on my sheet and it works fine, so i'm at a loss for now!